# Open browser type with javascript window.open()

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to open a specific browser type i.e. Google chrome, Firefox, Chromium using the window.open() method? For instance, I have Google chrome, Firefox and chromium installed on my system and would like to specify which one to open depending on the circumstances. Occasionally , I would also like to open all the browsers simultaneously and compare between browser performance.

Answer (score 4):

No that is not possible. If you are looking to automate browsers for javascript testing, there are tools like [js-test-driver](https://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/).